# Why findViewByID can call without super keyword

Tags: java, android

I'm new to java and android programming. As far as I know, `findViewById` was defined on parent classes and I'm just curious about why `findViewById` method can call without `super` keyword in child class.

Comment: In what cases do you think a `super` reference helps?

Comment: You only need to use super when you want to call the implementation in the parent class, if you have overridden the implementation in the current class. If you have no override, then `super.findViewById()` and `findViewById()` are equivalent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without overriding the `findViewById` method in the child class, `super` and `this` are equivalent within the scope of the Activity class.

You can do `this.findViewById()`, or `ActivityName.this.findViewById()`  but that is redundant unless inside an anonymous class (that is when you should use `ActivityName.this`, but that's outside the scope of the question)

Related question to ask: Why doesn't `setContentView` need a `super`?

Comment: >> But, the view that you are trying to find is in this class, not the super class, and the parent class implementation works fine, so no real need to override, IMO.....

i think this line is unrelated,

Comment: and `this` and `super` are not equivalent, `this` usually refers to current context, so if you are inside a anonymous class (like View.OnClickListener), `this` will mean the `OnClickListener` not the `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

`super` keyword refers to `SuperClass` (Parent Class) implementation, so when you call `super.findViewById(...)` you are accessing `SuperClass` method implementation, and since your `SubClass` doesn't override this method; `super.findViewById(...)` and `findViewById(...)` are equivalent.

But if you override it it will make a difference.
here is an example:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{

   void onCreate(....){
    View fromParentView = super.findViewById(...);
    View fromThisView = findViewById(...);
  }

  View findViewById(int resId){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
}
```

this first `fromParentView` will work correctly, but the `fromThisView` will throw an exception

please check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html